# How to correctly delete, update and create in REST API during one transaction

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-boot

I have the essence of the "Operation". There is an appropriate endpoint for deleting, updating and creating:

```
POST /api/operation
PATCH /api/operation/{id}
DELETE /api/operation/{id}
```

But there is a very complicated scenario. When a user can make changes in several operations in the interface, edit or create new ones, and all this time these changes are not sent to the server, but are saved on the browser side. Then the user can click on the save button and all these changes should be sent to the server.

The most difficult and incomprehensible thing is that all this must be performed within one transaction. Because if at least one operation was not successful, then everything should roll back.

And I do not yet have the right solution that would satisfy the rules of REST API.

I will give an example of how I see a solution to this problem. Passed json as follows:

```
[   
    "create": [
        {
            "name": "Operation New 1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Operation New 2"
        }
    ],
    "update": [
        {
            "id": 1
            "name": "Change operation name 1"
        }
    ],
    "delete": [
        {
            "id": 2
        }
    ]
]
```

And accordingly, the data from these three groups will be performed accordingly: create, update and delete

Further, this request is sent to some common endpoint with the POST method for example:

```
POST /api/operation/aggregate/create-update-delete
```

Please tell me how would you implement this scenario? Maybe someone faced such problems?

Although in this matter it does not matter what technology will be used, but I use Spring Boot, so if there are ready-made solutions for this technology, I will be glad to any help.

Comment: You can use the repositories of JPA for that and in CustomService you can handle as a transaction, putting `@Transactional` on the method that will do 4 actions on one, you can take a look https://spring.io/guides/gs/managing-transactions/

Comment: @JonathanJohx That won't help. Spring will commit the transaction after each REST call - resulting in three separate transactions.

Comment: So you want to commit one only on several requests? Because from controller enters to services ypu can manage the curremt transaction in order to do create/update/delete on the same transaction by using several commits.

Comment: interesting situation. Correct me if I am wrong but you probably need to actually perform each request/operation in order to track somehow user's actions (case in which you can just create a separate api for this). Otherwise not sure why would you choose not to perform only the final result, ex: create 1,2 delete 1 --> create 2

Comment: @dskfdskjgds you need to execute everything in one transaction. Since you cannot perform the deletion and then perform the update, an error will occur during the update, for example, due to the uniqueness of the fields. To avoid an inconsistent state

Comment: @JonathanJohx as I understand it, you need to do everything in one endpoint, and therefore you need one controller for all types of operations in one transaction